# My password don't works in graphical mode

Tags: 13.10

I've been Ubuntu user for 7 years and have 13.10 from it was launched, and worked Ok, until now. Now I have a problem, when I'm working in graphical mode and for example I try to use Synaptic, the authentication window opens and I type it, but the system doesn't accept the password. However, if I go to the terminal and type `sudo synaptic`, it asks me for my password, I type the same password, and Synaptic opens without any problem.

This is happening for any operation in graphical mode, what can be happening?

Comment: "*but the system doesn't accept the password*". You're going to have to be a lot more specific than that. What exactly happens? Also, what version of Synaptic are you using?

Comment: do **not** add (solved) to the question. There is a green check mark for indicating the correct answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd>  and enter :

```
gksu-properties
```

Now select Authentication mode `sudo`

[image]

It will solve your problem.

Comment: `gksu` is no longer installed by default in 13.10. This may however solve his problem still.

Comment: Well Friend I have tried but it didn't work, I think maybe the problem is not with sudo because it works, but I don't know how cal it the problem is working in graphicl mode, the system asks me autentication for operations which never before, and don't accept my password, but from terminal I don't have any problem.

Comment: in terminal instead of `sudo` use `gksudo` e.g. `gksudo gedit` let me know is it working?

Comment: Well I've used "gksudo gedit" and it worked Ok, it opened the autentication window and accepted the password without problem, but after it I tried to change mi default printer and dind'n let me do.

Comment: Oh thanks, now it is working Ok, it really worked. Thanks Guru for your help.